# Csv file writing a new row for each letter

Tags: python-3.x, csv

```
import csv

email = 'someone@somemail.com'
password = 'password123'
with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='') as accts:
    b = csv.writer(accts, delimiter=',')
    b.writerow(email)
    b.writerow(password)
```

I'm trying to append to a csv file with the format email:password on the same row, but everytime I run the program it creates a new row for each letter and the password is written under the email. What am I doing wrong?

Output:

```
s,o,m,e,o,n,e,@,s,o,m,e,m,a,i,l,.,c,o,m
p,a,s,s,w,o,r,d,1,2,3
```

Desired output:

```
someone@somemail.com,password123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string looks like a list of individual characters, and `writerow` expects a list of the column values, so you end up with columns of individual characters.

Instead, use a list of the column values:

```
b.writerow([email,password])
```